# Ethernet doesn’t have a valid IP configuration

Tags: windows, сеть, ethernet

Имеется кабель `Ethernet` и логин с паролем от провайдера. Через роутер все нормально ибо там есть поля где возможен ввод данных для провайдера.

Появилась потребность в подключении кабеля прямо к ноутбуку (роутер полетел). Есть адаптер `Ethernet`. При подключении кабеля к ноуту пишет `Неопознанная сеть`. Как правильно подключить? Где вводить логин и пароль?

Я знаю вариант что создается новое подключение, там вводятся логин и пароль. Но тогда тут проблема в том что я хочу раздавать инет с ноута, но выбрать созданное подключение я не могу.

Как быть? уже пробовал и драйвера переустанавливать и т.д.

Comment: А от чего конкретно этот логин и пароль. В роутере помимо этих полей есть такая вещь, как "тип подключение" и на винде надо исходить уже из этого типа. Это может быть pppoe или может быть какой нибудь из vpn (pptp, l2tp). Проще всего набрать в гугле например "windows 10 pppoe" (если это pppoe)

Comment: @Mike подключение pppoe что в роутере что в винде. В винде я создаю выскоскоростное подключение pppoe.